# Why are the latent heat of vaporisation values unavailable for cooking oils?

Tags: thermodynamics, food-chemistry

Oil evaporates. We know this, it's called the "smoke point". So why is it then, that whenever I try to find reference values for the latent heat of vaporisation for cooking oil, such as canola oil or olive oil, that the value is undefined in these tables?

Is it unknown? Or is the purity of cooking oil so variable that no scientist dares publish even an average amount of kJ/kg required to change oil from liquid to gas? Why is this information unavailable?

Follow‑up question: Is the information actually available and I've been unable to find it?

Comment: The smoke point is not the sign of evaporation, but decomposition. Additionally, they are mixtures with variable composition even for the single kind of oil.

Comment: Interesting. So indeed the "purity" is a factor, but you're mainly saying that oil is decomposing rather than evaporating, and that is why this information (latent heat of vaporisation of cooking oil) is unavailable, right? That's interesting because I now presume that cooking oil does not exist as a vapor, only as a solid and liquid, if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Exactly. Solid or liquid. If it had not been decomposing, its boiling point would have been MUCH higher then Teflon point of decomposition.

Comment: Thank you. I think you've answered my question… I'd be happy to accept your answer if you wanted to publish it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smoke point is not the sign of evaporation, but decomposition. Additionally, they are mixtures with variable composition even for the single kind of oil.

It means edible fats or oils are either solid or liquid. If they had not been decomposing, their boiling points would have been MUCH higher then Teflon point of decomposition.